# Drawable background работает неправильно(

Tags: android, android-studio, мобильная-разработка

Хочу задать background для activity. В моем ожидании должно выводиться изображение по центру и заданный фон, но получается, что изображение растягивается на весь экран.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@color/back"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screen" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. При использовании вашего кода и указании в качестве битмапа иконки размером 48х48 px, если поставить его бэкграундом на экран, то фон будет указанного в первом айтеме цвета, а картинка собственного размера (маленькая). Так и должно быть - при указании свойства `gravity` битмапу, он имеет собственный размер и не масштабируется (растягивается), если такая картинка больше экрана - она обрезается.

Comment: Скорее всего ваша картинка имеет достаточно больше собственные размеры, что занимает весь экран или нужно больше сведений, как именно вы используете этот бэкграунд, что получаете такой эффект.